# Where can I find a good comparitive study of the prasthana trayi commentaries?

Tags: bhagavad-gita, upanishads, brahma-sutras, book-recommendation

Are there any good editions of texts available online or offline that provide a side by side, comparative study of the commentaries on the Prasthana trayi (Upanishads, Brahma Sutras and Bhagavad Gita)? I am of course looking for 3 different texts, separately for each text. Links to book titles or actual file would be very much appreciated.

Comment: Do you need original commentary side-by-side or a book providing analysis of all commentaries would work?

Comment: @Pandya Now that you mention it, Former would be fine, latter is preferred. :)
I just need something that enables for quick references and also is in english or tamil. My knowledge of sanskrit or hindi is very elementary.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

1. Following are some books on Brahma Sutra comprising analysis of principal commentaries of Adi Shankaracharya (Advaita), Sri Ramanujacharya (Vishishtadvaita and Madhvacharya (Dvaita) available on Exotic India:

   - A Glossary of Technical Terms in The Commentaries of Sankara, Ramanuja and Madhva on The Brahma - Sutras (Set of 2 Volumes)

     > [image]
   - The Vedanta (A Study of The Brahma – Sutras with The Bhasyas of Samkara, Ramanuja, Nimbarka, Madhva and Vallabha)

     > [image]
   - [The Philosophy of the Vedanta Sutra (Brahmasutra): A Study based on the Evaluation of the Commentaries of Samkara, Ramanuja and Madhva](https://www.exoticindiaart.com/book/details/philosophy-of-vedanta-sutra-brahmasutra-study-based-on-evaluation-of-commentaries-of-samkara-ramanuja-and-madhva-IDE422/)
   - The Brahmasutras and Their Principal Commentaries A Critical Exposition (In Three Volumes)

     > [image]
2. For Srimad Bhagavad Gita, you can refer [bhagavad-gita.us](https://www.bhagavad-gita.us/bhagavad-gita-4-1/) where commentaries of Acharyas of various philosophies or Sampradaya are provided simultaneously verse-by-verse.  Also take a look at [Gitasupersite](https://www.gitasupersite.iitk.ac.in/srimad?language=dv&field_chapter_value=1&field_nsutra_value=1) where you can find various English translation and commentaries verse-by-verse.
3. For Upanishads, I've not found any source where all commentaries are comparatively provided. You can easily find Adi Shankaracharya's Bhashya on principle Upanishads on Internet Archive, Exotic India or from [Wisdom Library](https://www.wisdomlib.org/hinduism?sort=author) for Advaita and Rangaramanujacharya's Bhashya for Vishishtadvaita, see [vol 1](https://haristore.com/products/upanishad-bhashya-volume-i?refSrc=1361987338323&nosto=productpage-nosto-1), [vol 2](https://haristore.com/products/upanishad-bhashya-volume-ii?refSrc=1361987338323&nosto=productpage-nosto-1) and [vol 3](https://haristore.com/products/upanishad-bhashya-volume-3).

Answer (score 0):

For Bhagavad Gita, you may want to check out the work of T.G. Mainkar

The book is

> A comparative study of the commentaries on the Bhagavad Gita by T.G. Mainkar

I believe it was published by Motilal Banarsidas, though I don't know if it still remains in print. http://www.mlbd.in