# Analysis of the Brahmasutra which chooses best (according to author) interpretation of a verse from among interpretations of three major schools?

Tags: philosophy, vedanta, brahma-sutras, book-recommendation

I want to know are there books that try to analyze Brahmasutra from an independent ,non-sectarian perspective or from Western perspective while also specifying views of major Vedantic schools. I know one such book is " The Structure and Meaning of Badarayana's Brahma Sutras: A Translation and Analysis of Adhyaya 1 (English and Sanskrit Edition) " by G.C Adams, but it's only for Adhyay one,is there something like this for entire Brahmasutra?

Comment: please edit your question. by asking for 'best' rather than 'other' you are asking for opinions. see the guidelines for asking questions.

Comment: @SwamiVishwananda Is the question appropriate now?

Comment: Check [this answer](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/a/29938/277) if it helps you?

Comment: @Pandya thanks..that was indeed helpful.

Comment: @user1952500 "Western perspective is not necessarily secular. It has a strong Christian affinity." - we are not supposed to edit and remove any biases of OP. It is OP's question not yours.

Answer (score 1):

George Thibaut who translated the Brahmasutra Bhashyas of both Sankara and Ramanuja performed a comparative analysis of every adhikaraNa that you can read in his [introduction to the translation of the Sankara Brahmasutra Bhashya](https://www.sacred-texts.com/hin/sbe34/sbe34001.htm).

One of the unexpected observations Thibaut made was  that among the two, Ramanuja's commentary was closer to that of Badarayana whereas Sankara's commentary was closer to that of the Upanishads!